# Getting type from a generic entity

Tags: c#

I have been stuck trying to use Microsoft's Identity in my projects for a while now. I dont know if the problem is because i dont have an SSL on my site. Even though i disable ssl from start of code no avail so i decided to create a strong identity system which is similar to Microsoft's identity but free of it. Im stuck in a way trying to get a type which I want to use as the type parameter for a method. Take a close look at my rubbish.

```
public class JonesUserManager<TUser>  where TUser: JonesUser
{ 
        public TUser GetUserById(typeof(TUser.Id) Id) 
        {
            return DbSet.Find(Id)?? default;
        }
}
```

Can you see that? I want to get the type of the user's class Id Property and then use it as the  type in the method. I just get a **cannot do member lookup on TUser because it is a type parameter**. Then under type typeof keyword, it shows **Identifier is a keyword. Type expected**

**Edit**
This is my JonesUser class

```
 public class JonesUser<T, N>
    {
        [Required]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        protected internal virtual T Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        protected internal virtual string UserName { get; set; }
        protected internal virtual bool TwoFactorEnabled { get; set; }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return this.UserName;
        }
       //Other implementation
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, while I'd absolutely encourage experimenting with identity management to learn how and why things work (and don't work), there's the obligatory warning about rolling your own for any production scenarios without a firm grasp on why an OOB solution doesn't give you what you need. It's a tricky area that can bite you fast.

That said, looking at your code, you're using a generic definition that says `<TUser>` has to be of the `JonesUser` type. This means when you're referencing TUser in your implementation, it has to at least implement any properties or methods available in `JonesUser`.

With this constraint in place, you've probably already got some concrete type for `Id` defined by `JonesUser`, so there's not a real reason to wing it when you're passing the parameter in for your method. If `JonesUser` has an `Id` of, say, type `Guid`, then your method can safely just say:

```
public TUser GetUserById(Guid id) { }
```

If this doesn't get you where you need to go, I'd recommend you add your code for `JonesUser` for a better look.

**Update:**
Based on your provided `JonesUser` class and its own generics, your `JonesUserManager` also needs to know about the values for `T` and `N` that apply to the `JonesUser` it is managing.

```
    public class JonesUserManager<TUser, TId, TOther> 
        where TUser : JonesUser<TId, TOther>
    {
        public TUser GetUserById(TId id) { }
    }
```

It's worth considering at this point -- do you really want the ID to be able to be anything? Even [Microsoft's implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.getuseridasync?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Identity_UserManager_1_GetUserIdAsync__0_) makes some concessions here.